# How can I manipulate certain server side responses? Specifically Ajax Responses? XXE Attack? Hybrid DNS Resolution?

Tags: csrf, burp-suite, dns-spoofing, xxe, dnsmasq

I would like to be able to switch back and forth between the real DNS and maybe setting a local DNS entry so I can manipulate AJAX responses for code security checks.

For instance if the server responds with Ajax on page 1 that page 2 is not authorized. I want to manipulate this to return my desired response to make sure when the java script executes as intended there is still correct policy and security measures in place on the server side to prevent unauthorized access by hackers.

I am trying to basically have an Ajax call go to my server or have my desired response in the workflow of the site. Normally I would do this be overriting the local DNS for the API server however in this project the website is on the same domain as it makes API calls to via Ajax. I want the website to be the website as is but the Ajax calls to be interacting with me.

I know this can be done in theory but I don't know what is the best way. I don't want to have to go and compile some custom browser.

I basically am trying to hack a website that I have been paid to assess without access to the server side code. I want to make sure they don't rely on JavaScript logic for security.

**UPDATE**
To explain better if I were to address this at the DNS level I want to selectively have the DNS resolved so domain.com/path goes to normal DNS ip address and domain/api/path goes to my IP address. In theory it can be done but I am wondering if there are any tools that manipulate on host local DNS level such behavior. I think I need my own DNS servers with instantly dying TTLs?!? Even then I wouldn't be surprised if chrome doesn't allow it.

I am also completely fine with changing data anyway along the path before my browser computes the complicated javascript from these API calls on the same domain.

Comment: Sounds like you want to mock ajax calls here.  There are some tools available for this.   You could also just use pure JS to override any ajax calls with your own response.  There's an example of this in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272698/how-to-fake-jquery-ajax-response

Comment: @pcalkins not exactly. I am trying to basically have an Ajax call go to my server or have my desired response in the workflow of the site. Normally I would do this be overriting the local DNS for the API server however in this project the website is on the same domain as it makes API calls to via Ajax. I want the website to be the website as is but the Ajax calls to be interacting with me.

Comment: seems like you could just add an entry to hosts file for that.... you'd just have a sort of "staging" server.

Comment: but the problem is I want to selectively have the DNS resolved so domain.com/path goes to normal DNS ip address and domain/api/path goes to my IP address. In theory it can be done but I am wondering if there are any tools that manipulate on host local DNS level such behavior. I think I need my own DNS servers with instantly dying TTLs?!? Even then I wouldn't be surprised if chrome doesn't allow it.

Comment: seems like the DNS would only resolve the domain name....not any paths.  A reverse proxy could do this methinks.

Comment: You could use Developer Tools on your browser, break points, and change whatever response reaches the script, no DNS/custom server/hosts file needed.

Comment: @ThoriumBR well that was my original plan didn't get any responses and the other user pcalkins was talking about DNS so I made edits and added being open to that. I know developer tools has replays and break points but haven't figured out a way to edit responces

Comment: @Neo put a breakpoint after the line that assigns the response to a variable and alter the variable on the console.

Comment: @ThoriumBR haven't successfully done it yet buy this seem to be what I needed. Thanks